# Why I get Error code 404?

Tags: tsung

After I run the test as:

```
tsung -f test.xml start
```

I get this:

```
$ cd /Users/samir/.tsung/log/20160910-1035
Apple-Mac-mini:20160910-1035 samir$ /usr/local/Cellar/tsung/1.6.0/lib/tsung/bin/tsung_stats.pl
creating subdirectory data 
creating subdirectory gnuplot_scripts 
creating subdirectory images 
warn, last interval (2) not equal to the first, use the first one (10)
No data for Bosh
No data for Match
No data for Event
No data for Async
```

Then, I try to run the local server to see the results:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

In the browser, if I visit `http://localhost:8080`, it will redirect to `http://localhost:8080/es/ts_web:status` which will result into:

```
Error response

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
```

However, other reports works fine, like `http://localhost:8080/graph.html`

Any idea? is `http://localhost:8080/es/ts_web:status` for the real time status? why I got error 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right , the tsung_stats.pl script generate report.html file , in the browser, visit http://localhost:8080/report.html, the index.html be created in tsung runtime by ts_controller_sup.beam , the ts_controller_sup.beam listen 8091 port, you need to visit http://localhost:8091/index.html in tsung runtime , you can read the code in ts_controller_sup.erl 100 line

Comment: Thank you Le, actually I am new to Erlang and Elixir, totally different tech than I knew before..